# Cannot get specific value from NDSolve (multiple functions)

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve six connected differential equations. This is my code:

```
Clear[Solution,P1,P2,P3,Pbar1,Pbar2,Pbar3,tmax];
tmax=2;
Solution=NDSolve[Rationalize @ {
P1'[t]==-0.01 0.99995 P2[t]-Pbar2[t] P3[t]+Pbar3[t] P2[t],
P2'[t]==-0.01(-0.99995 P1[t]-0.01 P3[t])-Pbar3[t] P1[t]+Pbar1[t] P3[t],
P3'[t]==-0.01 0.01 P2[t]-Pbar1[t] P2[t]+Pbar2[t] P1[t],

Pbar1'[t]==0.01 0.99995 Pbar2[t]+P2[t] Pbar3[t]-P3[t] Pbar2[t],
Pbar2'[t]==-0.01(-0.99995 Pbar1[t]-0.01 Pbar3[t])+P3[t] Pbar1[t]-P1[t] Pbar3[t],
Pbar3'[t]==-0.01 0.01 Pbar2[t]+P1[t] Pbar2[t]-P2[t] Pbar1[t],

P1[0]==0,P2[0]==0,P3[0]==1,Pbar1[0]==0,Pbar2[0]==0,Pbar3[0]==1},

{P1[t],P2[t],P3[t],Pbar1[t],Pbar2[t],Pbar3[t]},{t,0,tmax}]
```

No errors and I get the normal output. There is something wrong with it, because the plot doesn't look like I want it to. That is not your problem, but when I try to check the solution by:

```
P3[0]/.Solution
```

I get

```
{P3[0]}
```

when I expect to get

```
{1}
```

or something like that.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: The mistake is in the second argument of `NDSolve`.  It should be `{P1, P2, P3, Pbar1, Pbar2, Pbar3}`, without the `[t]` arguments.  Also, you don't need `Rationalize` here, but that's not a mistake.  Since `NDSolve` uses numerical methods, it's okay to pass it inexact numbers.

Comment: FWIW, I like to set up my equations with exact coefficients.  It makes certain things easier, such as adjusting the working precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Szabolcs wrote, you mentioned that the solution doesn't look like what you want it to be. Here is the solution using `tmax = 2`:

```
tmax = 2;
s = NDSolve[{P1'[t] == -0.01 0.99995 P2[t] - Pbar2[t] P3[t] + 
      Pbar3[t] P2[t], 
    P2'[t] == -0.01 (-0.99995 P1[t] - 0.01 P3[t]) - Pbar3[t] P1[t] + 
      Pbar1[t] P3[t], 
    P3'[t] == -0.01 0.01 P2[t] - Pbar1[t] P2[t] + Pbar2[t] P1[t], 
    Pbar1'[t] == 
     0.01 0.99995 Pbar2[t] + P2[t] Pbar3[t] - P3[t] Pbar2[t], 
    Pbar2'[t] == -0.01 (-0.99995 Pbar1[t] - 0.01 Pbar3[t]) + 
      P3[t] Pbar1[t] - P1[t] Pbar3[t], 
    Pbar3'[t] == -0.01 0.01 Pbar2[t] + P1[t] Pbar2[t] - 
      P2[t] Pbar1[t], P1[0] == 0, P2[0] == 0, P3[0] == 1, 
    Pbar1[0] == 0, Pbar2[0] == 0, Pbar3[0] == 1}, {P1, P2, P3, Pbar1, 
    Pbar2, Pbar3}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]
Plot[{P1[t], P2[t], P3[t], Pbar1[t], Pbar2[t], Pbar3[t]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

And here it is using `tmax = 300`:

```
Plot[{P1[t], P2[t], P3[t], Pbar1[t], Pbar2[t], Pbar3[t]} /. Solution, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Why don't you include the solution from the comment into the answer, to make it complete?

Comment: Added in the correction.

Comment: As messy as it may look, yes. That looks more like it! Thank you.